# Button with assigned product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

Must create a Button which will add assembly price to the basket (assembly is a virtual product).

```
<!-- ADD ASSEMBLY SERVICE -->

        <?php
            $_sku = 'ASSEM1';
            $_assembly = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);
            $url = Mage::helper ( 'checkout/cart' )->getAddUrl ( $_assembly, array ('qty' => 1 ) );
        ?>  
            <form method="post" name="form-name" action="<?php echo $url;?>">
            <button type="submit" style="width: 100%;" class="button btn_goto"><?php echo $this->__('Buy Assembly for this product') ?></button>
            </form>
<!-- END ADD ASSEMBLY SERVICE -->
```

This works but this method redirect to the cart so customer must go back to the product page, but product or buy product then go back again to buy assembly service. Is there any other possible way to add assembly as a product (must be separately added to the invoice). Custom option is not good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ajax instead of `form` to add product to Cart.
Remove form tag and update button code like

```
<button type="button" style="width: 100%;" class="button btn_goto" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $url;?>');"> <?php echo $this->__('Buy Assembly for this product') ?></button>
```

Put JavaScript function

```
<script>
function addToCart(url){
$j.ajax({ 
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Assembly product added successfully.");
    } 
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't make it work ....

Comment: Url seems to be ok, but  execution actually does nothing :(

Comment: Aaaah silly me ;)